# Unlocking keyring opens browser

Tags: browser, keyrings

When I start up my computer (Ubuntu 12.10), it asks to unlock my keyring.
After unlocking my browser (Chrome) opens two "about:blank" tabs out of nowhere.
If I already had the browser open, it just opens the two new tabs next to the existing ones.

Chrome is configured to open only the New Tab page, Google Cloud Print is off and I unchecked the "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" options.

I looked in Startup Applications (and I 'unhid' the entries in /etc/xdg/autostart) but I couldn't find it there.

How do I fix this? It's not really a big problem, but it's annoying. And I don't want my system to have quirks like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just having this problem and fixed it by going to Settings -> Online Accounts and removing my Google account (it was the only one I had, so you might have to do it for others as well).